# nodejs fs.rm(path, { recursive: true, force: true }) throws "ENOTEMPTY: directory not empty"

Tags: javascript, npm, electron, rm, node.js-fs

```
import { existsSync } from "fs";
import fs from "fs/promises";

export async function makeFolder(path: string) {
if (existsSync(path)) {
try {
await fs.rm(path, { recursive: true, force: true });
} catch (e) {
console.log("ERROR", e);
}
}
await fs.mkdir(path, { recursive: true });
}
```

[ENOTEMPTY: directory not empty](https://i.stack.imgur.com/3BS2F.png)

In the dist/resources folder there is a file called default_app.asar. When deleting the file manually the command works but when it's restored by `npm install` the error is back. I checked and the file is not used by any process.

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem was the asar file from the`/dist/resources` folder.

Fixed by setting

```
process.noAsar = true
```

Before calling the following function

```
fs.rm()
```